# FOR ALL/EXIST Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, exists, forall

I am following an online course on databases. However, I really don't know what the next step is and how I can answer this question. Can anyone please help?
This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT P.name
FROM Persons P 
LEFT JOIN Knows K ON K.personA_id = P.id
WHERE K.age >= P.age
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a08fcf/6)

```
SELECT distinct P1.name
FROM Persons P1 
INNER JOIN Knows K ON K.personA_id = P1.id
INNER JOIN Persons P2 ON K.personB_id = P2.id AND P1.age - P2.age > 5
```

It will output everybody that knows 1 person or more (personA) and that every person known is more than 5 years younger (personB)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! A part of the list that it returns is correct but it misses one name name that is five years older. Do you know why that may be?

Comment: Your question said "more than 5 years older" so if it's 5 years, it's not included

Comment: Yes, you're right. But could you also show me how it would be done if 5 years is included?

Comment: Just play with `P1.age - P2.age > 5`...so if you also want to include 5 years, put `>=` instead

Answer (score 1):

The title of the question referred to using `ALL/EXISTS`. Here's are approaches that actually do that:

```
/* all */
select p.name
from Persons as p
where p.age - 5 > all (
    select p2.age
    from
        Knows as k inner join
        Persons as p2
            on p2.person_id = k.personB_id
    where p2.id = p.id
)

/* not exists */
select p.name
from Persons as p
where not exists (
    select p2.age
    from
        Knows as k inner join
        Persons as p2
            on p2.person_id = k.personB_id
    where p2.id = p.id
        and p2.age > p.age - 5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.name
FROM Persons p
WHERE p.age > 
    ((SELECT p1.age 
     FROM persons p1
     INNER JOIN knows k
     ON p1.id = k.personB_id)
     + 5)
```

Something similar to this should work. I haven't tested this but the basic idea is there. You have to compare the age of table 1 to the ages of everyone known in table 1 by running a sub query on table 2. There are other ways but this seemed the easiest. Try it and let me know if you get any errors. Enjoy :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I get the error "Subquery returns more than 1 row". Do you know what that could be?

Comment: The subquery is returning multiple rows because there are multiple people known. It's hard to think about with out the actual tables but it should be something close to this. Are you familiar with `IN`?

Comment: I sort of know what it is, but I think that the exercise doesn't want me to use it. Do you have any other suggestions to fix this?

Comment: You could use `max(p1.age)` inside the subquery to reduce it to a single row.